# How to use filter hook "the_posts" with a function that refers to $this?

Tags: wp-query, filters, hooks, feed

I'm using Carbon Fields to manage event-related metadata (such as event dates) for certain posts on my site, but I want to make sure that past events do not show up in my site's feeds. I need to use the filter `the_posts` with a function. Here is my code:

```
add_filter("the_posts", "filter_past_events");

function filter_past_events($posts) {
    if ($this->is_single) {
        return $posts;
    }
    if ($this->is_feed) {
        for ($i = count($posts) - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
            $event_meta = carbon_get_post_meta($posts[$i]->ID, "event_meta");
            if ($event_meta) {
                $is_future = false;
                if (!empty($event_meta[0]["scheduling_blocks"])) {
                    $scheduling_blocks = $event_meta[0]["scheduling_blocks"];
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($scheduling_blocks); $j++) {
                        if (DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("m/d/Y H:i:s", $scheduling_blocks[$j]["start"]) > new DateTimeImmutable()) {
                            $is_future = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!$is_future) {
                    array_splice($posts, $i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

I am getting `Fatal error: Too few arguments to filter_past_events(), 1 passed`. What am I doing wrong? Has WordPress stopped passing the WP_Query object `$this` to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/), the 2nd argument passed to functions hooked to `the_posts` is the `WP_Query` object.

To access it you need to define the 4th argument of `add_filter()`, `$accepted_args`, to `2`, so that you can accept it.

Then you just need to accept 2 arguments in your function, and use the 2nd argument to as the `WP_Query` object:

```
function wpse_313327_filter_past_events( $posts, WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_single() ) {
        return $posts;
    }

    if ( $query->is_feed() ) {
        // etc. etc.
    }

    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse_313327_filter_past_events', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
I'm not quite sure why I need to set `$accepted_args`: it seems rather arcane to have to tell WordPress how  many arguments your function has if it is clearly documented how many it will try to pass. But that's WordPress.

Comment: It's not WordPress. Not really. When you hook a function WordPress runs it using `call_user_func_array()`. If it runs that function and sends all the possible arguments but your callback function doesn't accept all the arguments then PHP will throw an error. The only solutions are either to force hooked functions to accept all arguments, thus making it impossible to ever add new arguments to hooks in future versions, or make all additional arguments optional and require the hook to declare how many it supports. Choice seems clear to me.

Comment: It also means that if you wanted to add a function like `strip_tags` to a filter then you couldn't just use `add_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_tags' )` , because `strip_tags()` does not have exactly the same number of arguments as the `the_content` filter sends.